# getting arrays and replacing spaces with comma

Tags: arrays, variables, str-replace

I'm working on something the whole day and night but it seems like i'm not getting any further with it cause it's a bit complicating for me to learn actually :(

The code is like this:

```
    $aDoor = $_POST['zeilenid'];
  if(empty($aDoor))
  {
    echo("You didn't select anything.");
  }
  else
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);
    echo("You selected $N entry ID(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)

    {
      $str = $aDoor[$i];
      $str = ereg_replace(" ",",",$str);
      echo($str . " ");
    }
  }
```

it doesn't work tho - i want the IDs, which will showing to NOT show them this way: 8 9 10
but rather this way: 8, 9, 10
and save it in ONE variable! how cna i make this happen? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try:

```
    $aDoor = $_POST['zeilenid'];
  if(empty($aDoor))
  {
    echo("You didn't select anything.");
  }
  else
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);
    echo("You selected $N entry ID(s): ");
    echo join(", ", $aDoor);
  }
```

join combines all elements of the array into one string and inserts the first parameter between each element

edit: save it:

```
$str = join(", ", $aDoor);
```

Comment: damned, seems like to work like a CHARM!!! thanks for your excellent and quick help, wow!

Answer (score 0):

```
$clean_search = str_replace(' ', ',', $user_search);

    $search_words = explode(' ', $clean_search);

    $final_search_words = array();

    if (count($search_words) > 0) {
        $final_search_words[] = $user_search;
      foreach ($search_words as $word) {

        if (!empty($word)) {

          $final_search_words[] = $word;

        }

      }

    }
```

This code will replace empty space with comma, and the if condition is used to replace extra spaces with only one space.